# How to make the backcolor of a button blink in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I was making a millionaire app and I want the backcolor of a button to blink each time a correct question is answered

Comment: If you want to do anything after a time period and/or regularly without user intervention, use a `Timer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where ever you have your code to determine correct answer...

```
If answer = "Correct" Then
    Timer.Enabled = True
End If
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If Button1.BackColor = Color.Red Then
            Button1.BackColor = Color.LightGray
        Else
            Button1.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
        If Button1.BackColor = Color.LightGray Then
            Timer1.Enabled = False
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Dim hold = who.getUserAns(res)
    If hold = "1" Then
Timer.Enabled = True
End If
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If Button1.BackColor = Color.Red Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.LightGray
    Else
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Red
    End If
    If Button1.BackColor = Color.LightGray Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

this worked, but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

What if you want the button to blink forever, or want something more dramatic than a blink?

Animated GIF images and WAV sounds are pretty neat.  They work in any control that accepts an image.

Download a "Celebration" GIF file from the web or create one.
Download a "Celebration" WAV file from the web or create one.

```
Button1.Image = Image.FromFile("YourHappyDance.gif")
My.Computer.Audio.Play("YourHappySong.wav", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
Button1.image = Nothing
```

With AudioPlayMode set to WaitToComplete, Line 3 does not execute until the sound/song is over. Hence, delay.  You can place Line 3 in a loop to increase the delay.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Timer1.Start()
End Sub

// put this routine in your main form 
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        If Button1.BackColor = Color.Red And Timer.Enabled = True Then
            Button1.BackColor = Color.LightGray
        Else
            Button1.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
        If Button1.BackColor = Color.LightGray Then
            Timer1.Enabled = False
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).